# Reverse each word of user given string without altering their position

Tags: java, string, reverse

I need a little help. I found a question like **"Write a Java program that will reverse each word of user given string without altering their position and using any built in function."**

I solved a code for reversing the whole sentence, but I don't  know how to solve this one. Please help me...

```
import java.io.*;
class test25 { 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        String s = br.readLine();
        String reverse = "";
        int length = s.length();

        for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse = reverse + s.charAt(i);
        System.out.println("Result:" + reverse); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Check my answer. That's the method to achieve it. Do u need working code or can you do it from this?

Comment: Do you need to achieve this without using any inbuilt functions?

Comment: Accept answer if you got what you need.

Answer (score 5):

1) Split your sentence (using split(), this will return an array, say words[])

2) Reverse each word in the array words[].

3) Reconstruct your sentence from the array words[].

Answer (score 5):

```
String str = "hello world";
String revStr = reverseWordByWord(str);

 public String reverseWordByWord(String str){
        int strLeng = str.length()-1;
        String reverse = "", temp = "";

        for(int i = 0; i <= strLeng; i++){
            temp += str.charAt(i);
            if((str.charAt(i) == ' ') || (i == strLeng)){
                for(int j = temp.length()-1; j >= 0; j--){
                    reverse += temp.charAt(j);
                    if((j == 0) && (i != strLeng))
                        reverse += " ";
                }
                temp = "";
            }
        }
        return reverse;
    }
```

**Input: hello world**

**Output: olleh dlrow**

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple code that implements @Maximin's answer.

```
public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String input = br.readLine();
        String[] words = input.split(" ");
        String reverse = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            for (int j = words[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                reverse += words[i].charAt(j);
            }
            System.out.print(reverse + " ");
            reverse = "";
        }
    }
}
```

The reversed strings could also be placed into their own array by declaring `String[] reverse = new String[words.length];`, allowing you the option to reconstruct the sentence or format output as desired.

Comment: You used a inbuilt function sir !

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ReverseWord {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "My name is Sarthak ";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int n = s.length();
    int j =n;
    int i;
    for(i = n-1;i>=0;i--){

        if(s.charAt(i) == ' '){
            sb.append(s.substring(i+1, j));
            sb.append(" ");
            j = i;
        }
    }
    sb.append(s.substring(0,j));
    System.out.println(sb);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

split the string using space and then loop through each element of String array and reverse it:

public class StringReverse {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
String eString=" \"This is the one\"";
String double_quoteString[]=eString.split("\"");
eString=double_quoteString[1];
String[] splitStrings=eString.split("\\s+");
String reverse="";
for(int i=0;i<splitStrings.length;i++)
{
    if(i!=0)
    reverse+=" ";

    for(int j=splitStrings[i].length()-1;j>=0;j--)
    {
        reverse+=splitStrings[i].charAt(j);
    }
}

reverse="\""+reverse+"\"";
System.out.println("reverse is "+reverse);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
class sort
{
public static void main(String[] aaa)
{
String s;
String rev="";
String temp=" ";
Scanner ob=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" enter String");
s=ob.nextLine();
for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    rev=rev+s.charAt(i);
System.out.println(rev);
String[] a=rev.split(" ");
int j=a.length-1;
while(j>=0)
{
    temp=temp+a[j];

    temp=temp+" ";
    j--;

}
System.out.println(temp);
}
}
```

I too tried this.Since I am learning java i tried this code in simple way.If i did any mistake in code or logic please correct me.Thank you....;

Comment: Ok, I am upvoting it then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```
public static String reverseEach(String inputString) {
  String[] parts = inputString.split(" ");
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (String p : parts) {
    sb.append(new StringBuffer(p).reverse().toString());
    sb.append(' ');
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0,j=0;
            string test = "Hello Sir I am good";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            char[] str = test.ToCharArray();
            char[] revstr;
            while (i < str.Length)
                i++; 
                i--;
            for (int k = i; k >= j;)
            {

```
            if (str[k] == ' ')
            {
                for (int l = k; l < i; l++)
                {   

                    sb.Append(str[l+1]);

                }
                sb.Append(" ");
                i = k - 1;  
            }
            k--;

        }
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            sb.Append(str[j]);
        Console.WriteLine(sb);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please better format your code :)

Answer (score 0):

very simple code is here

```
class reverse{
    public static StringBuilder sb;    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {        
       String str[] = "He is the one".split(" ");        
       String finalStr="";            
       for(int i = str.length-1; i>= 0 ;i--)    
       {                
            finalStr += str[i]+" ";
            finalStr.toString();

            sb=new StringBuilder(finalStr);
            sb.reverse();              
      }         
       System.out.print(sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i also faced a similar question but didn't clear the round because my approach was too complex for the person evaluating my answer, i am sharing it here, hope it helps someone.

```
package interviewPractice;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SentenceToWord 
{
    public static int getNumberOfWords(String sentence)
    {
        int counter=0;
        for(int i=0;i<sentence.length();i++)
        {
            if(sentence.charAt(i)==' ')
            counter++;
        }
        return counter+1;
    }

    public static char[] getSubString(String sentence,int start,int end) //method to give substring, replacement of String.substring() 
    {
        int counter=0;
        char charArrayToReturn[]=new char[end-start];
        for(int i=start;i<end;i++)
        {
            charArrayToReturn[counter++]=sentence.charAt(i);
        }
        return charArrayToReturn;
    }

    public static char[][] getWordsFromString(String sentence)
    {
        int wordsCounter=0;
        int spaceIndex=0;
        int length=sentence.length();
        char wordsArray[][]=new char[getNumberOfWords(sentence)][]; 
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            if(sentence.charAt(i)==' ' || i+1==length)
            {
            wordsArray[wordsCounter++]=getSubString(sentence, spaceIndex,i+1); //get each word as substring
            spaceIndex=i+1; //increment space index
            }
        }
        return  wordsArray; //return the 2 dimensional char array
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter the String");
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput=input.nextLine().trim();
    int numOfWords=getNumberOfWords(userInput);
    char words[][]=new char[numOfWords+1][];
    words=getWordsFromString(userInput);
    System.out.println("Total number of words found in the String is "+(numOfWords));
    for(int i=0;i<numOfWords;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(" ");
        for(int j=0;j<words[i].length;j++)
        {
        System.out.print(words[i][j]);//print out each char one by one
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Now you have your words stored in the array "words" just reverse them.

Answer (score 0):

here is one solution

```
fucntion String reverseSentence(String sentence){
String Rword = "";
String newSentence = "";
char space = ' ';
String empty = "";

if(sentence == null || sentence == empty)
return null; // this could be an error message
else{
      int tempi = 0;
         if(sentence.charAt(0) == space){ 
              Rword = Rword+sentence.charAt(0); // check for when the first char is a space
              tempi++;
         }
        for(int i=tempi; i< sentence.length(); i++){
             if(sentence.charAt(i) == space) //if it reaches a space its a word
             {
                Rword = Rword+sentence.charAt(i);  //add the current space
                newSentence = newSentence+Rword ; //give the reversed word to the new sentence
                Rword = ""; // then empty the word
             }else{
                    Rword = sentence.charAt(i)+Rword ; //while its not a space, reverse.  
                  }
        }
          newSentence = newSentence+Rword; // the last char might not be a space to so the first 
                                           //  if statement in the loop will never happen again, 
                                             //i add the last word after the loop
          return newSentence;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different solution and a simple one

```
public class strrev {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the string to be reversed");
        String str=br.readLine();
        char rev;
        int k=0;        
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {           
            if(str.charAt(i)==32 ||i==str.length()-1)
            {
                for(int j=i;j>=k;j--)
                {
                    rev=str.charAt(j);
                    System.out.print(rev);
                }
                k=i;
                continue;
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution: 
First we enter a enter a string through a scanner
Then we split it by spaces. 
Then we reverse it using a for loop and output it.

```
     public class reverse{

             public static void main(String[] args){

                 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

                 System.out.println("enter string");

                    String s = sc.nextLine();

                    String [] words = s.split(" "); // space for words

                    for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                 {

                    System.out.print(words[i] + " ");

                 }
            }
}
```

Comment: "Write a Java program that will reverse each word of user given string without altering their position and using any built in function." Whereas your program leaves each word in tact, but alters it's position. Also invalid syntax on > = because you can't have a space between.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse string

```
     import java.util.*;

     public class Main
   {
        public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         String m="java is           great";
          String temp="";
          System.out.println(m);
          String store="";
           int cnt=0;
       char [] p=m.toCharArray();
      for(int i=p.length-1;i>=0;i--)
       {
       if(p[i]==' '||i==0)
            {
        if(cnt>=1||i==0)
        {
            if(i==0)
                temp=temp+p[i];
            store=store+new StringBuilder(temp).reverse().toString();
            temp="";
            cnt=0;
        }
        if(p[i]==' ')
        {
          store=store+p[i];
        }


    }
    else
    {
        temp=temp+p[i];
        System.out.println(p[i]);
        cnt++;
    }
       }
     System.out.println(store);
   }
 }
```

Output.    great          Is java

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s;
    s="hi Mister geek is here";//input string 
    int j=0;//for tracking each word
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)//loop for the string 
    {     
        if((int)s.charAt(i)==32/*if has  space checked by ascii code of the space */||i==s.length()-1/* for the end of string */)
        {
            for(int u=i;u>=j;u--)// loop for each word
                System.out.print(s.charAt(u));

            j=i; 
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class p3`
//Reverse each word of user given string without altering their position
{
public static String reverseWord(String word)
{
    String r="";
    int len=word.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
    r=word.charAt(i)+r; 
    }
    return r;   
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        String s = br.readLine()+' ';
        String rev="",s1="";
    int l=s.length();

    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if (s.charAt(i)!=' ')
        {
        rev=rev+s.charAt(i);

        }
        else
        {
        rev=reverseWord(rev);
        s1=s1+rev+" ";
        rev="";
        }   
    }


    System.out.println(s1);
}}
```

Comment: Please provide some description along with the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through my approach.It will provide you correct output:-

```
public class ReverseWordByword {
    private String sentence="My java virtual world";
    private String newReverse;

    public ReverseWordByword() {
        newReverse="";

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReverseWordByword().wordReverse();
    }
    public void wordReverse(){
        String arr[]=sentence.split("\\ ");

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            newReverse=newReverse+reverseLogic(arr[i])+" ";
        }
        System.out.println(newReverse);
    }
    public String reverseLogic(String word){
        String localWord="";
        char[] charArr=word.toCharArray();
        for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            localWord=localWord+charArr[i];
        }

        return localWord;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this function will take a string as input and would reverse the string.

```
public static String reverseWordWise(String input) {

    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    String reversestr = "";

    for(int i = words.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(i == words.length-1){
            reversestr = reversestr + words[i];
        }else{
            reversestr = reversestr + " " + words[i];
        }
    }//end of for loop

    return reversestr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReverseEachWord {

    static void reverseEachWordOfString(String inputString)
    {
        String[] words = inputString.split(" ");

        String reverseString = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
        {
            String word = words[i];

            String reverseWord = "";

            for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) 
            {
                reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
            }

            reverseString = reverseString + reverseWord + " ";
        }

        System.out.println(inputString);

        System.out.println(reverseString);

        System.out.println("-------------------------");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        reverseEachWordOfString("");

        reverseEachWordOfString("");

        reverseEachWordOfString("");

        reverseEachWordOfString("");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String reverseString(String s) {
    String res = "";
    String reverseFirstPart = "";
    String reverseLastPart = "";

        for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++){
            if (s.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ") ){
                String firstPart = s.substring(0,i);
                String lastPart = s.substring(i+1,s.length());
                reverseFirstPart = new StringBuilder(firstPart).reverse().toString();
                reverseLastPart = new StringBuilder(lastPart).reverse().toString();
                res = reverseFirstPart + " " + reverseLastPart;
            } else {
                res = s.substring(i,i+1)+res;
                }
    }  return res.substring(reverseLastPart.length());
}
```

Comment: You should not post only code, explain your solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hello dear";
    String su= "";
    //split the words
    String words [] =s.split(" ");
    //iterate each word and reverse using sb.reverse
    //and append in the string with " "
    for (String w:words) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(w);
        sb.reverse();
        su += sb.toString()+" ";
    }
    System.out.println(su.trim());
    //prints "olleh raed"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
        for ( String rs : s) {
            System.out.print(new StringBuilder(rs).reverse()+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReverseSent {
    public String Reverse(String s) {
        String s1="",s2="",s3="";
        int l = s.length();
        for(int i=1;i<=l;i++) {
            if(s.charAt(l-i)==' '||(l-i)==0) {
                for(int j=1;j<=s2.length();j++) {
                    s1=s1+s2.charAt(s2.length()-j);
                }
                s3=s3+s1+" ";
                s1="";
                s2="";
            }else if((l-i)==1){
                s2=s2+s.charAt(l-i)+s.charAt(0);
            }else {
                s2=s2+s.charAt(l-i);
            }
        }
        return s3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReverseSent rs = new ReverseSent();
        String s = "Hello   i am ashish";
        System.out.println(rs.Reverse(s));

    }

}
```

input: Hello   i am ashish

output: ashish am i   Hello

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.learning.misc;

public class WordReversal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "functional Interface is core concept of Lambda";

    char arr[] = str.toCharArray();

    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == ' ' || i == arr.length-1) {
            for (int j = i; j >= temp; j--) {
                System.out.print(arr[j]);
            }
            temp = i+1;
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

package com.practice.stringCodes;

public class ReverseStringWordsWithoutSplit {

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    String reversedString = "";
    String givenString = "My name is vishal kumar";
    givenString = " " + givenString;
    while(givenString.contains(" "))
    {
    reversedString += (givenString.substring(givenString.lastIndexOf(" "), givenString.length()));
    givenString = givenString.substring(0, givenString.lastIndexOf(" "));
}
    System.out.println(reversedString.trim());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple using the inbuilt functions: split & reverse. However my code is helpful for those who want the solution without using those functions.
`import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ReverseWordSentence {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the phrase to be reversed: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phrase = sc.nextLine();
    char[] ch = phrase.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Character> wdl = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(int i=0; i<ch.length; i++) {
        if(String.valueOf(ch[i]).equals(" ") || (i == phrase.length()-1) ) {
            if (i == phrase.length()-1) {
                wdl.add(ch[i]);
            }
            
            for(int j=wdl.size()-1; j>-1;--j) {
                System.out.print(wdl.get(j));
            }
            
            if(ch[i]==' ') {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            
            wdl.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            wdl.add(ch[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: welcome to SOF. Some parts of your code are out of code block. Plus, can you do some unit testing and refactoring to improve your code? Tip, try not to nest loops and conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

**Given a String S, reverse the string without reversing its individual words. Words are separated by dots.**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "i.love.java";
    String[] words = s.split("\\.");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = words.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        sb.append(words[i]);
        if( i != 0){
            sb.append(".");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Your solution is reversing the whole sentence and not individual words.

Comment: Answer does not resolve the asked question.